# How does access delegation work - Access Token work?

Tags: oauth2

I'm trying to understand how do access tokens work. What is the mechanism used to generate access tokens similar to AWS Secure Token Service or OAuth Tokens.

I am assuming the algorithm is as follows:

1. Person A authenticates themselves to AuthServer
2. Person A sends a message to AS saying "Get me a token that i can give to someone to acess resource Y on my behalf". This message is signed by A's private key and sent to AuthServer which verifies the signature.
3. AuthServer creates a token. Token contains a random byte-string that is signed by the AuthServer
4. AuthServer stores a entry in it's private database associating the decrypted token with information that authorizes anyone bearing the token to access resource Y on behalf of Person A
5. Person B authenticates themselves to AuthServer
6. Person B sends the Token received by Person A to AuthServer
7. AuthServer verifies the token and verifies if Person B has access to resource Y

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: You're asking how a general concept is implemented. That's not really a question with an answer as there's many ways someone could implement tokens.  Your example is one way it could be implemented. Are you really asking if your implementation of access tokens is **secure**?

Comment: No, my intent is to learn how this is designed. Looking for some articles or designs where I can learn more about this more in detail.